# How to not showing the coordinates (x,y) when mouse move?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm able to make a svg file using gnuplot. when I click any place in the plot, the (x,y) coordinates will show up, when the mouse move, the coordinates change, when I click the plot again, the coordinate disappear.

How to not display the coordinates when mouse click and move? 
Thanks!

I have tried:

```
set mouse noruler

set mouse mouseformat 6

set mouse mouseformat ""

set mouse clipboardformat 6
```

The code is:

```
set term svg mouse jsdir "http://.../TEST/"

set output "test.svg"

plot 'test.data' using 1:2:3 with labels hypertext point pt 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I initially misunderstood your question (1st answer now deleted). Let me try again.

You are describing the default behaviour of mousing support in gnuplot+svg.

(1) **Simple option**: If you don't want any of this, do not include the `mouse` keyword when you select the terminal.

(2) **Infinitely customizable option**: The javascript mousing behaviour is implemented in a separate file `gnuplot_svg.js`. Several versions exist, but you could edit or replace any of them to suit your needs.  The most recent version is here:
    [gnuplot_svg.js](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main/ci/master/tree/term/js/gnuplot_mouse.js)

(3) **Possible compromise**:  The `*.svg` file produced by gnuplot contains lines like this:

```
<g id="gnuplot_canvas" onclick="gnuplot_svg.toggleCoordBox(evt)" onmousemove="gnuplot_svg.moveCoordBox(evt)">
```

If you want to disable only the response to mouse clicks, or to mouse movement, edit these lines to remove the corresponding `onclick` or `onmousemove` directives.

Comment: Thanks!  In gnuplot_svg.js file, I set visibility to hidden, which solved the problem.